# MERN stack cannot connect to database to Docker Container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, mern

Good day... regarding for integration the MERN stack web application on docker using dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml.. the localhost:8000 is where my backend, also localhost:3000 is where my frontend ports..and i'm running it on locally.. the credentials on mongo is correct..then i put networks in docker-compose and driver: "bridge", there are on the same network.. after i build container and running the application on docker.. the error stated below:

```
[0] [http-server] listening: http://localhost:8000/
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.20.0.3/
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /maint/client/public
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
[1] Starting the development server...
[1]
[0] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
[0] ERROR: Cannot connect to the database
[0] Exiting now...
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

my dockerfiles :

```
# get the base node image
FROM node:10.15.2

# set the working dir for container
WORKDIR /maint

# copy the json file first
COPY ./package.json /maint

RUN "npm ci"

# copy other project files
COPY . .

# build the folder
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

and inside of my docker-compose-local.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    maint:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      command: npm run dev
      container_name: mat-docker
      volumes:
        - ./:/maint
        - /maint/node_modules
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      depends_on:
        - mongo
      networks:
        - app-network
    mongo:
      image: mongo
      container_name: mat-dockerdb
      ports:
        - "27017:27017"
      env_file: .env
      environment:
        - MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_HOST
        - MONGO_DB:$MONGO_DB
        - MONGO_USERNAME:"admin"
        - MONGO_PASSWORD:"password123"
      networks:
        - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: How is your application connecting to the database?  In Docker, 127.0.0.1 is usually "this container", which from the application's point of view isn't where the database is running.  You might read through [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation, which explains what host names will be available to Compose applications.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this much easier by just using the host network. This way your main service and mongo instance use the same host network as your backend. Here is an example of a docket compose app to do this

```
 version: "2"
 services:
 app:
    container_name: app
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000”
    depends_on:
      - mongo
 mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @Edward Romero, my concern is  "Cannot connect to the database" is it automatically connected? if i integrate the simple code by your example? and is it ok to not include the ports: 8000 as it is my backend? thanks

Comment: I’ll edit my response, so that it includes the network host option so that your backend can connect as well

Comment: ,, you add network_mode: host and depends_on: -mongo.. both mongo and app same network_mode:host

Comment: This disables most of Docker's networking functionality, and I wouldn't recommend it.  `ports:` have no effect; if you do use `app` and `mongo` as host names to communicate between containers, that stops working; if you want to not publish an internal container's ports, host networking removes that choice.

Comment: @neiljosephpeña how are you hosting your backend? is it another docker compose?

Comment: Edward Romero no idea.. on backend i do not have docker compose on it